# failed to create .ensime file, how can I do?

Tags: scala, sbt, ensime

I have been trying to use ensime with sublime to use Scala. To install ensime I created a plugin.sbt in this location

> ~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/plugins.sbt

[here is the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ipPG.png)
I also added "addSbtPlugin("org.ensime" % "sbt-ensime" % "2.0.1")" in the plugin.sbt. But when I run sbt and run the command "ensimeConfig" to create .ensime file I get error

```
C:\Users\Mahadi>sbt
"C:\Users\Mahadi\.sbt\preloaded\org.scala-sbt\sbt\"1.0.1"\jars\sbt.jar"
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; sup
port was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Mahadi\.sbt\1.0\plugins\project
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt ...
[info] Loading global plugins from C:\Users\Mahadi\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\Mahadi\project
[info] Set current project to mahadi (in build file:/C:/Users/Mahadi/)
[info] sbt server started at 127.0.0.1:5547
sbt:mahadi> ensimeConfig
[error] Not a valid command: ensimeConfig
[error] Not a valid project ID: ensimeConfig
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: ensimeConfig
[error] ensimeConfig
[error]             ^
sbt:mahadi>
```

So I am looking for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Youn should run **sbt** in the root directory of your sbt project, as the ensime configuration file is built based on it.